# Jquery, sum form field values and pass on to next page on form submit

Tags: jquery

This code is to Sum and subtract prices from the checkbox with a start Value using jquery.
My question is how to pass the new Total Calculated Value on the form Submit to the next page for further processing.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="tst">
<label id="subt0" data-original="8.90">8.90</label>

<input name="service1" type="checkbox" id="ser1" data-price="1" value="1" title="Service 1" />
<input name="service2" type="checkbox" id="ser2" data-price="5" value="1" title="Service 2" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var subt_value = parseFloat($('#subt0').text());
var start_price = parseFloat($('#subt0').attr('data-original'));
        
        $("#ser1, #ser2").click(function(){
    
            var sub_total = 0
            var extra_fee = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price')/1.12).toFixed(2);
                        
            $(this).each(function(){
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    var sub_total = subt_value + parseFloat(extra_fee);
                    $('#subt0').text(parseFloat(sub_total).toFixed(2));
                }else{
                    $('#subt0').text(parseFloat(start_price).toFixed(2));
                }
            });
           
            
       });       
       </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you can use hidden fields or global variables in this case,to pass the value of Sum to next form

Comment: Yes, but how to put the new total in hidden field.

Comment: Give the hidden field an id so that you can refer to it and set the value.

Comment: Can someone write it down the working code based on the above example.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this
In  HTML

```
<input type="hidden"  id="test" />
```

and in script assign that value to the hidden field based on the id.
like this

```
var a=10;
var b=10;
var c=a+b;
 $("#test").val(c);
```

Hopefully it will work for you.Cheers!!!